# How to refer custom jquery and bootstrap path in karma-html-detailed-reporter's reporter.js file?

Tags: testcase, nunit, test-report

I am new to TDD. Currently, I had run more than 2000 test cases parallel with chrome headless browser using [concurrently-npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). All the test cases are working fine. If any of the test cases get failed means, I have found the test result for each folder with [karma-html-detailed-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html-detailed-reporter).

I have been generated the coverage report as JSON reports and then converted them to HTML report with [istanbul-combine package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-combine). I have configured the gulp tool to perform multiple tasks for all test cases folders. I am hereby to share sample gulp tasks for one of my folder,

**gulp.js file:**

```
/**
* Generates json code coverage report in folder reporters/new
*/
gulp.task('new', function (done) {
 return new Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.new.js',
    action: 'run',
    singleRun: true,
    preprocessors: {
        'js/**/**/**/*.js': ['coverage'] //' js/**/**/*.js'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'htmlDetailed', 'coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
        dir: './cireports',
        subdir: "reporters/json_reports",
        reporters: [
            { type: 'json', file: "new.json" }
        ]
    },
    customLaunchers: {
        MyHeadlessChrome_Mobile: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: ['--disable-translate', '--disable-extensions', '--remote-debugging-port=9223', "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=500,500"],
        }

    },
    browsers: ['MyHeadlessChrome_new']
}, done).on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
}).start();
});
```

I have multiple karma-configuration files for each test case folders. I am hereby sharing one of my karma configuration file.

**karma.config.js :**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({
  browsers: ['Chrome', 'IE', 'Firefox', 'ChromeHeadless'],
  frameworks: ['jquery-1.10.2', 'jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
  files: [
'js/**/**/**/**.min.css',
'js/**/**/**/**/*.min.css',
'js/*/*/new/*.js',  
{
    pattern: 'js/**/**/Index.html',
    watched:true,
    served:true,
    included:false
}
],
port:9888,
browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
captureTimeout: 100000,
reporters: ['progress', 'htmlDetailed'],
htmlDetailed: {
        splitResults: false,
        dir: 'cireports/nunit/new',
        fileName:'TestResult.html',
        autoReload: false,
        useHostedBootstrap: true
    },
coverageReporter: {
  type: "html",
  check: {
    each: {
      statements: 0,
      branches: 0,
      functions: 0,
      lines: 0
    }
  }
}
});
};
```

**package.JSON :**

```
{
"name": "gulp-karma",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
 "test": "gulp test",
 "ci": "gulp ci",
 "coverage": "concurrently \"gulp zero\" \"gulp one\" \"gulp two\"",
 "coverage_report": "concurrently \"gulp generate_newcoverage\" \"gulp generate_combined_coverage\"",
"lint": "gulp runeslint"
 },
"devDependencies": {
 "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
 "eslint-html-reporter": "^0.5.2",
 "ghooks": "^1.2.4",
 "gulp": "^3.9.1",
 "gulp-csslint": "^0.3.1",
 "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
 "gulp-jasmine": "^2.4.1",
 "gulp-lesshint": "^2.0.0",
 "gulp-shell": "^0.6.3",
 "istanbul-combine": "^0.3.0",
 "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
 "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
 "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
 "jquery-1x": "^1.10.2",
 "karma": "^1.7.1",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
 "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
 "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
 "karma-html-detailed-reporter": "^1.1.20",
 "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
 "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
 "karma-jasmine-jquery-2": "^0.1.1",
 "karma-jquery": "^0.1.0",
 "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0"
 },
 }
```

After the test case execution, the test result for the folder will generate in `"cireports/nunit/..."`

But in my source, only `TestResult.html` only generated, the bootstrap and JQuery was not created in that Nunit folders with karma-html-detailed-reporter. Even though, if I set the `"useHostedBootstrap: true"` value to true, the bootstrap and JQuery files were not created in my unit folder.

The following code shows the `reporter.js` file default code :

**karma-html-detailed-reporter/lib/reporter.js:-**

```
if (useHosted) {

    template = template.replace(/\{\{jquery_Path\}\}/g, 'https://code.jquery.com');

    template = template.replace(/\{\{bootstrap_Path\}\}/g, 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7');

} else {

    var basePaths = getRelativePaths();

    template = template.replace(/\{\{jquery_Path\}\}/g, basePaths.jquery);

    template = template.replace(/\{\{bootstrap_Path\}\}/g, basePaths.bootstrap);

 }
 .....
 .....      
 function getRelativePaths() {
    var paths = {};

    // Get bootstrap's path
    var bootstrap = require.resolve('bootstrap');
    if (!bootstrap) log.error('Bootstrap is not found!');
    else {
        bootstrap = require('path').dirname(bootstrap);
        bootstrap = splitResults ? path.relative(outputDir + '/tempFolder/', bootstrap) : path.relative(outputDir, bootstrap);
        paths.bootstrap = bootstrap.substring(0, bootstrap.indexOf("\\js")).replace(/\\/g, '/');  // <- This gives the path of the '/js' subfolder of bootstrap, so we need to go one level up
    }

    // Get jquery's path
    var jquery = require.resolve('jquery');
    if (!jquery) log.error('jQuery is not found!');
    else {
        jquery = require('path').dirname(jquery);
        paths.jquery = (splitResults ? path.relative(outputDir + '/tempFolder/', jquery) : path.relative(outputDir, jquery)).replace(/\\/g, '/');
    }

    log.debug('Paths: ', paths);
    return paths;
 }
```

In the above code, I want to refer to custom JQuery and bootstrap location with my source. because `useHostedBootstrap` was not working in `karma-html-detailed-reporter`. That's why I've switched into a custom location for JQuery and bootstratp. My bootstrap and JQuery paths are,

**Bootstrap.min.js :**

> "My_Folder\cireports\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"

**Bootstrap.min.css :**

> "My_Folder\cireports\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css"

**jquery.min.js :**

> "My_Folder\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js"

And also, I had posted an issue regarding this, [custom jquery and bootstrap path](https://github.com/a11smiles/karma-html-detailed-reporter/issues/17) in karma-html-detailed-reporter-issues.

Could anyone tell me, how to refer my locations in `karma-html-detailed-reporter/lib/reporter.js` file?